# I need to change language input when focus on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to change language input when focus on input

[image]

I need any way to change language input on focus in `input[type="text"]`

**Script**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <input type="text" id="myClass" lang="arabisk" /> 
    
    <script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        // change to arabic input language
        $(document).on('focus','.myClass',function(){
            // .... code here  
        });
        // change to english input language
        $(document).on('outfocus','.myClass',function(){
            // .... code here 
        });
        
    });
    
    </script>
```

My objective is : change language when focus, or on focus {alt+shift}

Comment: Something like change attr function in jquery
$(document).on('focus','.myClass',function(){
           $('#myClass').attr( 'lang','To what you want'); 
        });

Comment: on focus change language input to Arabic automatic

Answer (score 0):

Using the `attr` function of jquery.

```
<input type="text" id="myClass" lang="arabisk" /> 

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    // change to arabic input language
    $(document).on('focus','.myClass',function(this){
        this.attr('lang', 'arbasic')
    });
    // change to english input language
    $(document).on('outfocus','.myClass',function(this){
          this.attr('lang', 'eng')
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: i'm sorry this is not my problem, look at the picture plz , i need to change language input

Answer (score 0):

Changing the language of the system is not possible by client side javascript. That would be a major security risk. Javascript has limited access to the client it runs